# need help in understanding javascript code

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone explain me the following piece of code

```
sampleQuery.replace(new RegExp("("+query+")","ig")
```

What is this "ig" stands for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `i` and the `g` are flags used with Regular Expressions:

`g` - '**global**' matching - ie. gets *all* matches (the default behaviour is to stop after one match is found. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp

`i` - makes the matches **case-insensitive**. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp

hth.

Comment: Please don't refer to W3Schools: see [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com) why. Use [MDC's RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp) instead.

Comment: I'm agreeing with Marcel, W3Schools shouldn't be used as any kind of reference seeing they got outdated and terribly wrong information up there.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using it for quick n dirty answers such as this for novices - in my experience newbies find the interactive JS tool very useful.

Comment: I would avoid the term *greedy* here as it normally refers to some other behaviour in the context of regular expressions (`.*` vs `.*?`).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel - btw that W3Fools article links to a bunch of stuff that is apparently unmaintained and imho less useful than W3Schools.

Comment: Ah, I see, but at least it explains what's wrong with W3Schools. And as you say: those answers become quick and *dirty*: those newbies will come back soon when they bluntly copy-pasted such an advice on W3Schools containing lots of security holes and illogical advice.